# What is the differences between pycocoevalcap Bleu and NLTK Bleu methods for bleu score calculation

Tags: python, nltk, bleu

For image captioning, Bleu score can by calculated by using pycocoevalcap repo or NLTK Python library like:

```
`from utils.coco_caption.pycocoevalcap.bleu.bleu import Bleu      # // by pycocoevalcap
.
.
.

from nltk.translate.bleu_score import corpus_bleu                 # // by nltk

.
.
.`
```

What is the difference between them?